# Google does not index my images - using sitemap, multi-lang subdomains and static subdomain

Tags: sitemap

Most of my images cannot be found in the Google Image Search.
I have submitted Google Sitemaps. There are no problems reported on Search Console, but only 1 image out of 34 is indexed. I suspect my multi-language setup could be a problem.

I have a website with serves output in different languages. For each language I have a subdomain: `de.openisles.org` and `en.openisles.org`.

For each of the language domains I have a sitemap, for example with the language-dependent text.

My sitemap entries look like this:

```
<!-- de.openisles.org/sitemap.xml -->
<url>
    <loc>http://de.openisles.org/media/screenshots/2016-01-03-demanded-goods.html</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://static.openisles.org/media/screenshots/2016-01-03-demanded-goods.png</image:loc>
        <image:caption>Infopanel: verlangte Güter</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>

<!-- en.openisles.org/sitemap.xml -->
<url>
    <loc>http://en.openisles.org/media/screenshots/2016-01-03-demanded-goods.html</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://static.openisles.org/media/screenshots/2016-01-03-demanded-goods.png</image:loc>
        <image:caption>Info panel: Demanded goods</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

The two websites link each other, so that Google knows it's the same content in another language.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.openisles.org/media/screenshots/2016-01-03-demanded-goods.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.openisles.org/media/screenshots/2016-01-03-demanded-goods.html" />
```

Because images are not language-dependent (I do not want them to be) I have an additional subdomain `static.openisles.org`. To tell Google that my static server belongs to me, I added this subdomain also in the Search Console.

---

My question is simple: What am I doing wrong? Why is Google not indexing my images?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that nothing is wrong with your sitemap, especially if Google Search Console doesn't say anything.

Google has its own algorithm for what to index and what not to index, and submitting a sitemap does not guarantee indexing; it only helps Google to more fully map out your website, if it decides to crawl it.

I've submitted a sitemap for a library with contained 4,000,000 urls, but its been close to a month now and Google's only indexed around 14,000.

I think the fact that even one of your images has been indexed is a good sign - Google was able to find it! Have patience, my friend, and I think you'll find the other images will slowly get indexed as well.

Best of luck!

Comment: Well, I have been patient for over half a year now, so I am beginning to worry that something is wrong on my side.

Comment: Well, that changes the story a bit.... I'm not sure what else you might be able to try. It'd be a last-ditch effort, but you could perhaps send Google an email asking if multi-language sitemaps affect crawling?

Comment: Hey! Im in the same situation as you are, with around 259 images, i just got indexed like 20... did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I haven't really found a solution to getting Google to index everything. I check the stats page every once in a while, and Google tells me that it's visiting however many pages a day. So at the very least, Google is looking at my pages and I'm just going to leave it at that.